# call_user_func vs variable variables in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a significant difference between call_user_func and using variable variables?

Take for example a class such as this:

```
class someClass{

    protected function action_this() { ... }
    protected function action_that() { ... }

}
```

Is this better or more efficient

```
class myClass extends someClass{

    public function doAction($action='this'){
        $method="action_{$action}";
        if(is_callable (array($this,$method)) ){
            call_user_func(array($this,$method));
        }
    }

}
```

than

```
class myClass extends someClass{

    public function doAction($action='this'){
        $method="action_{$action}";
        if(is_callable (array($this,$method)) ){
            $this->$method();
        }
    }

}
```

Are there conditions under which one might be preferred over the other?

Comment: If you're passing arguments to a function, which do you think would be more appropriate or easier to use?

Comment: AFAIK, `call_user_func` is just the older way -- it was the only way to do it before they added variable functions. Now I would use variable functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example lacks clarity.

Normally it's better to have some understandable code:

```
$callback = array($this, $method):

if (is_callable($callback)) {
    call_user_func($callback);
}
```

However depending on taste, you might prefer:

```
if (is_callable($callback)) {
    $callback();
}
```

I wouldn't favor the one over the other but take the one that works.

That being said I would strongly try to not make use of magic at such a point and I personally prefer to call explicitly defined methods by their defined name and not by variable. Just to not introduce hard to debug magic.